# Azure : Problems while Creating X-509 certificate

Tags: azure, x509certificate, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to create a X 509 certificate and upload it to Azure Portal. However, after I followed the steps from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-create-certificates) link, I am unable to VERIFY the certificate on the Azure Portal.

NOTE :

- I have used the generated verification code from the Azure Portal for the registered certificate.
- Azure Portal does NOT flash any error.
- Mine is a FREE Trial Azure Account.

Can anyone help me in the following :

- How do I trace Azure Portal Logs ? How can I track if I encountered any errors while uploading certificate.
- What could have been a possible reason for this issue ?

Look forward to your help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This known issue has been fixed now.In addition, you can also use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az_iot_hub_certificate_verify) to work around for certificate verification.

1. Download the Azure CLI from [here](https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCliWindows),and install it in your local PC;
2. Open powershell and run as administrator;
3. Execute the `az login` command to login with your Azure Account;
4. Upload the CA certificate file you have generated to IoT Hub through executing the following command:

   `az iot hub certificate create --hub-name <azure-iot-hub-name> --name <certificate name> --path <certificate file path>`
5. Generate a verification code for the certificate using *`az iot hub certificate generate-verification-code`*. You can view the  from Azure Portal:

   `az iot hub certificate generate-verification-code --hub-name <azure-iot-hub-name> --name <certificate name> --etag <ETag>`
   [image]

After executed successfully,you will get the response from Azure including the *verificationCode*, according with this code, generate the verification certificate file.

6. Verifies the certificate by using the following cmdlet. Please note that, int this step you need to reacquire the *ETag* because it has been refreshed in last step:

   `az iot hub certificate verify --hub-name <azure-iot-hub-name> --name <certificate name> --path <erification certificate file> --etag <ETag>`

In the end, the certificate will be verified.In addition you can get more introductions about Azure CLI Command from here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Unfortunately, does not seem to work I have tried CLI as well. I get the error mentioned in https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5376

I have raised a ticket for the same. Can you let me know what might have gone wrong from my side ?

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Azure Portal. Please try to verify the certificate again in Azure Portal.

Comment: Sorry but Does not work. I cannot go past teh verification / proof of possession step.